# Fetch Nested Json Value under single Column name using Azure Cosmos Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Based on my requirement my project can have multiple tasks, and each tasks can have sub tasks under it.

I need to fetch all the task name for that particular project under one column based on the assignee. Trying to write a cosmos db query for the same. But how to fetch all the sub tasks name as well under one column based on Assignee.

I am not able to do union as well in cosmos db
[image: Requirement]

Below is the json format for the same :

```
  {
"ProjectName": "Abc",
"Tasks": [
{
        "TaskName": "Create Customer Profile",
        "StartDate": "2022-05-09T00:00:00",
        "CompletionDate": "2022-05-10T00:00:00",
        "Assignee": "Abdul Saleem",
        "Approver": "Akshat Soni",
        "SubTasks": [
            {
                "SubTaskName": "t5",
                "StartDate": "2022-05-11T00:00:00",
                "CompletionDate": "2022-05-13T00:00:00",
                "Assignee": "Abdul Saleem",
                "Approver": "Akshat Soni"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "TaskName": "Create Customer Profile",
        "StartDate": "2022-05-09T00:00:00",
        "CompletionDate": "2022-05-10T00:00:00",
        "Assignee": "Abdul Saleem",
        "Approver": "Akshat Soni",
        "SubTasks": [
            {
                "SubTaskName": "t5",
                "StartDate": "2022-05-11T00:00:00",
                "CompletionDate": "2022-05-13T00:00:00",
                "Assignee": "John",
                "Approver": "Akshat Soni"
            },
            {
                "SubTaskName": "t5",
                "StartDate": "2022-05-11T00:00:00",
                "CompletionDate": "2022-05-13T00:00:00",
                "Assignee": "Abdul Saleem",
                "Approver": "Akshat Soni"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The below query worked for me. I am not sure if it is the best way possible, but it worked. I will update it if I optimize the current solution.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(c2.TaskName,c2.SubTaskName,c2.SubTask1Name) TaskName FROM 
(SELECT ARRAY(SELECT c.ProjectName,i.PhaseName,tb.TaskName FROM c   join i in c.Phases join t in i.Tasks where t.Approver = 'GTS Test') as TaskName
,ARRAY(SELECT c.ProjectName,i.PhaseName,s.SubTaskName as TaskName FROM c join i in c.Phases join t in i.Tasks join s in t.SubTasks where s.Approver = 'GTS Test') as SubTaskName
,ARRAY( SELECT c.ProjectName,s1.SubTask1Name as TaskName FROM c join i in c.Phases join t in i.Tasks join s in t.SubTasks join s1 in s.SubTasks1 
where s1.Approver = 'GTS Test') as SubTask1Name FROM c) as c2
```